# OpenOffice/LibreOffice Impress messing up master slides when saving in native (ODP) format

Tags: ubuntu, slideshow, openoffice-impress, libreoffice-impress

I want to have several master slides in my presentation so I created them in `View ► Master ► Slide Master.` The background images of my master slides are different (I added the images to each master slide by right clicking in its background and selecting `Slide ► Set Background Picture for Slide`). Then I styled my presentation using the master slides I configured. It looks OK but when I save my presentation in ODP format, next time I open it the slide backgrounds are all messed up.

Seems curious to me that this doesn't happen when I save the presentation in Microsoft Office PPT format. Is someone there working for the competition?

Any workaround for this? Am I just doing something wrong?

Edit: I'm using LibreOffice 3.2.2 in Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's a bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/openoffice/+bug/316023

You can change the background in normal view, right-clicking on the slide (and selecting "this slide only")... as a poor work-around.

Or, the "traditional way" using different backgrounds (colors, pics, etc.) on master slides:

Create your masters
Select the first master
"F11" to show the styles window
Select Background style > Modify > Aera > Fill > Bitmap

NB: you must first import your pictures as a bitmap images, selecting menu: Format > Area > Bitmap > Import your photos [and set the correct options] -- that's maybe the catch?

Repeat with the other Master copies.

Comment: Thanks. If I import my images as bitmaps, will they be available even if I move the ODP file to a different machine?

Comment: @Sergio This is unrelated. Custom bitmaps/colors will be available to every new file you create (this is a user profile setting). You can either keep them, or remove them, after document creation. It will not affect the existing documents odp odt you have created with these custom bitmaps/colors.

Comment: I've just checked, and this bug has now thankfully been marked as fixed & released in LibreOffice.